# EnvDTE in c#: how do i add parameters to a generated c++ function?

Tags: c#, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to generate a function with parameters. adding the function header and body works fine, but when I try to add parameters I get an exception that I haven't been able to solve.

```
func.AddParameter("num", "int");
```

I get the exception:

> Failed to return new Code Element. Possibly syntax error. New Element Name: num

this is how I generated the function head and body:

```
VCCodeFunction func = (VCCodeFunction)(((VCFileCodeModel)(file.FileCodeModel)).AddFunction("testfunc", vsCMFunction.vsCMFunctionFunction, "testClass2"));
func.BodyText = "for(int i=0; i < 5; ++i){}\n return 1;";
```

this generates:

```
testClass2 testfunc()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {}
    return 1;
}
```

as a temporary solution I get around the issue by manually adding the parameters one character left from where the body starts (or within the parenthesis)

```
var tp = func.GetStartPoint(vsCMPart.vsCMPartBodyWithDelimiter);
var ep = tp.CreateEditPoint();
ep.CharLeft();
ep.Insert("int num");
```

but I feel this is bad practice.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is imaginative casting.  The [documented method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vccodemodel.vccodefunction.addparameter?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_VCCodeModel_VCCodeFunction_AddParameter_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_) has three arguments.

Comment: i'm sorry I don't know what imaginative casting is, and I couldn't find anything about it on the web. also, I get the same exception if I add the third argument which is 0 by default. can you elaborate?

Comment: Consider using vsCMTypeRefInt for the 2nd argument.

Comment: I have tried that. it yields the same result